# Getting null when trying to read a column with value '-' from aws glue catalog table

Tags: apache-spark, aws-glue

I am reading an Athena table which has a column name br_book_gl1 which has values as '-' and '+'.
[Athena Source data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJWew.png)
I am getting the '+'value when reading it as glue catalog table but for '-' values, I am getting null.
The datatype is String in Athena table and I am using the below code:
gluecontext.getCatalogSource(database = database, tableName = tableName).getDynamicFrame().toDF()
.select(col("br_book_gl1").as("GainLossSign"))

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNEmh.png)

Answer (score 1):

Athena can only read table names with alphanumeric or underscore characters.

See this page for more info: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/console-tables.html?icmpid=docs_glue_console.